'Invalid account data for instruction' with Deploying to Mainnet Using Playground
I am deploying a program using Playground. The same account and code run perfectly on the devnet. However, when deploying to the mainnet, it fails at a certain stage with the following error:
error:
Deployment error:
Instruction index: 0
Reason: Invalid account data for instruction.

I don't understand what causes this issue. Can someone help me with this?

it could be that you don't have enough space in your program's data account as well. Could you share a failed tx ? will check if there is more data (or your wallet address, the one you use to deploy your program). Also, has this program already been deployed successfully on mainnet in the past ?

The most likely issue is that it's working on devnet because all the accounts there are initialized but not on mainnet.
Try making sure that all the accounts and programs you are interacting with on mainnet-beta are initialized
